# "tel:" redirects to main page with URL like www.siteName/tel:nbr

Tags: html, tel

On some browsers or mobiles (don't know exactly which) "tel" redirects user to www.siteName/tel:nbr
[On this site](http://%20https://www.astanasu.kz/en/) when click on 1302 call center

```
<a href="tel:1302">1302</a>
```

Comment: It can happen when the device does not have facility to call see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying this the right way? like this

```
<a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111">+1 (303) 499-7111</a>
```

Comment: Well its <a href="tel:1302">1302</a>

Comment: There's some browser compatibility issue there i think, that's causing the problem. 
[See details here](https://caniuse.com/?search=tel)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the property this way,

```
<a href="tel:1302">1302</a>
```